# Tmux always shows hostname instead of application running

Tags: zsh, tmux, prezto

A weird thing is happening. I have been trying to debug it for 2 days with no luck. Nothing relevant around forums as well.

I have just set up my wife's machine because I need to work remotely. I have transferred all my set up from my own desktop to my wife's laptop so everything should work just fine. And they do except a small thing which I cannot find out why it's not working. My desktop runs MX Linux 18.3 and my wife's laptop runs MX Linux 19.1

Configuration:

MX Linux 19.1, tmux, zsh, prezto, vim

So the problem now. When I open my terminal under tmux, the status-right shows the hostname. This is all good. When I open VIM though, the status_right pane_title still shows the local hostname while my desktop shows that vim is running plus the full path of the file opened by vim. Same with any other app e.g. htop. My wife's laptop does not update the status-right pane_title while my desktop does. I don't have access to my desktop at the moment so I will only post images of how it looks on my wife's laptop.

Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try and set the title manually by doing:

```
printf '\033]2;test_title\007'
```

And make sure tmux is working correctly.

But - it is the application's responsibility to set the title, and although vim may set it by default, htop normally doesn't.

So I suspect your shell was doing it for you.

Check your shell profiles on both boxes (both the default ones and any changes you have made), I'd say either there is something you forgot to change to make it set the title, or something that now needs to be enabled, or it has been removed between versions.

Comment: printf '\033]2;test_title\007' sets pane_title correctly. I checked gnome-terminal and I couldn't find any setting I am missing. I also installed the latest zsh 5.8 (previous one was 5.7.1). Also tested zsh, tmux with xterm and xfce terminal and still the same behavior. So it's something more general causing this. Could be OS related?

Comment: Moreover, after calling "printf '\033]2;test_title\007" `test_title` is set and is not changing back to hostname or any other value if I enter/exit applications e.g. vim, nano, htop

Comment: It is nothing to do with your terminal, it is almost certainly your shell. You need to look closely at your zsh config and the default zsh config, or any differences between the two zsh versions you are using. nano and htop do not set the title, the only thing that knows the application and could be changing the title for them is the shell.